# Why is "Droxine" a name appropriate for someone beautiful and pleasant?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, names

In *Star Trek*, season 3, episode 21, "The Cloud Minders", Spock is considering his surroundings at the time, and one of its residents:

> Here on Stratos, everything is incomparably beautiful and pleasant: the high advisor's charming daughter, Droxine, particularly so.  The name *Droxine* seems appropriate for her.

Why?  Does *droxine* mean something, or is it related etymologically or homophonically to something?  (Perhaps in Vulcan?)  Why does that name seem appropriate to someone who is beautiful and pleasant?

Comment: "*Droxine: a sodium salt used to treat thyroxine deficiency.*" - Magical.

Comment: @Valorum Well, it probably sounds pretty good if you _are_ suffering from thyroxine deficiency...

Comment: @DavidW - Especially if your people have struggled against the oppression of the evil Levothyroxine Empire

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyzine was sold under the brand Droxyne (pronounced the same way as Droxine) until the 1970s. It causes drowsiness and has "hallucinogenic and hypnotic" propoerties

Comment: @Valorum if that's correct, it sounds very likely like the correct answer.  Thanks! Might I suggest you post it as an answer, below? I've also just found [the related but weaker claim](https://trekmovie.com/2008/07/14/the-cloud-minders-remastered-review-video-screenshots/) that "'Droxine' is almost certainly a play on 'Hydroxyzine,' a drug sythesized in the 1950’s as an antihistamine which turned out to have powerful anti-anxiety properties. It is an effective 'sedative, hypnotic, and tranquiliser,' just like Plasus’ daughter." No mention of a brand name, but that doesn't mean it's not so.

Comment: @msh210 - If someone posted it as an answer, I'd downvote it. We don't go in for guesswork around these here parts.

Comment: tvtropes claims  "probably derived from Hydrox, a creme-filled chocolate sandwich cookie" https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/StarTrekS3E21TheCloudMinders

Comment: @Valorum in the absence of a better answer we absolutely do allow for 'guesswork', unless the OP specifically says they're not interested in those answers.

Comment: [Hydroxyzine](https://medlineplus.gov/druginfo/meds/a682866.html)